# RestKit does not recognize path pattern with params

Tags: ios, api, http, restkit

I have path pattern

```
api/v1.2/user/:userId/friends
```

for get list friends by given userId

It will be a simple get query, but then i do register responseDescriptors for this key path, and then do call api method like

```
[self.api getObjectsAtPath:@"api/v1.2/user/:userId/friends" parameters:@{ @"userId" : @1 } success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
    NSLog(@"Friends");
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error");
}];
```

I got error and full URL path was http://localhost/api/v1.2/user/:userId/friends?userId=1

RestKit does not replace path param.

But i also use Retrofit in Android programming, and there it's simply to do

```
@GET("/group/{id}/users")
List<User> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId);
```

How do RestKit replace path params?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really compare different libraries for different platforms...

To inject parameters you need to use an `RKRoute` to set up your request. The route deals with creating the path and injecting the parameters where as calling `getObjectsAtPath` does not attempt to inject any parameters.